# TypeScript declare specific SCSS module

Tags: typescript, sass, module

I'm trying to declare a specific SCSS module to import from TypeScript. I have this declaration file that is working well:

```
declare module '*.scss' {
  const styles: {
    a: string
    b: string
    c: string
  }

  export default styles
}
```

But I'd like to narrow down `*.scss` somehow so that this declaration file only applies to the SCSS file `_variables.scss` which is located in the same directory.

I have tried to replace `*.scss` with `_variables.scss` or `./_variables.scss` but then TypeScript wasn't able to find the module declaration at all.

Is this possible with TypeScript?

Answer (score 3):

You can do your module declaration like this. Read more on wildcard module declarations [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#wildcard-module-declarations).

```
declare module '*_variables.scss' {
  const styles: {
    a: string
    b: string
    c: string
  }

  export default styles
}
```

Comment: do you know why it won't allow an exact path? I would like to receive TS errors when I import `_variables.scss` from the wrong location. Do you know if this is possible with TS at all? I don't see any explicit note of this in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

I tested different cases to import `_variables.scss`. I think @JoshA's answer is a great way to be flexible with different (absolute, relative) paths of your file. However, as you mentioned in a comment, you would like to get TS errors when you import `_variables.scss` from the wrong location.

For this purpose, I created a folder `assets` in the root directory. I created then `_variables.scss` and `_variables.d.ts` in `assets` folder. Then, I included './_variable.d.ts' in types of tsconfig.json.

```
root
   /assets
          _variables.dt.ts
          _variables.scss
```

In my tests, I realised that it is important to have an absolute path, which you will later use for importing `_variables.scss` in your .ts files. For example, I use Nuxt.js and you can define there root path by `~`. If I need to import `_variables.scss`, I will always use

```
//someFile.ts
import SomeVariableName from `~/assets/_variables.scss`
```

Therefore, if I define my `_variables.d.ts` file as shown below, everything will work, as you need.

```
//_variables.d.ts
declare module '~/assets/_variables.scss' {
  const styles: {
    a: string
    b: string
    c: string
  }

  export default styles
}
```

As you see, the path to `_variables.scss` is exactly the same for import and declare statements: `~/assets/_variables.scss`. You will not be able to import the file with relative paths. For example, these would not work:

```
import SomeVariable from '../assets/_variables.scss'
import SomeVariable from './assets/_variables.scss' 
import SomeVariable from '../_variables.scss'
import SomeVariable from './_variables.scss'
```

To conclude, if you define in `declare module 'Absolute-Path-of-_variables.scss-File-As-You-Import-It-In-Other-.ts-files' {}` absolute path to `_variables.scss` and import it with the same path in .ts files, everything should work for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the entire path of the `import` in the `declare module`.

So if your file exists in `../foo/bar/_variables.scss`

make the declare

```js
declare module '../foo/bar/_variables.scss' {
  const styles: {
    a: string
    b: string
    c: string
  }

  export default styles
}
```

Comment: that this approach doesn't work is exactly the problem I'm facing. The SCSS file is located in the same directory as the module declaration file. So `./_variables.scss` _should_ work as a relative path, but does not.